# Can you save the current desktop background as an image?

Tags: macos, photos, desktop

I've deleted a photo by mistake. I have the photos as my desktop background. Is there any way that I can take it and save it?

Answer (score 5):

Go to **System Preferences** → **Desktop & Screen Saver** and **drag the image out of the image well**.

[image]